# How add a group by to the query used by the media library?

Tags: filters, media-library

What would be the proper way to add a group by to the media library query? What I have tired so far is not working:

```
add_filter('posts_groupby ', 'limitMediaLibraryItems', 10, 2 );
function limitMediaLibraryItems($groupby) {

    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/upload.php' ) !== false ) {    
        $groupby .= " guid";
    }

    return $groupby;
}
```

Updated:
Maybe the correct approach is to use the ajax_query_attachments_args filter. How could this be made to work?

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'hide_duplicate_guids', 10, 1 );

function hide_duplicate_guids( $query = array() ) {

    $query['group by'] = 'guid';

    return $query;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `GROUP` are of _very_ limited use in post queries. Also it's strange to see `guid` used as non–unique field?..

Comment: It is not strange at all. Every item in the media library represents an attachment and some of our attachments will point to the same image file. By adding the group by we will eliminate duplicate images from the library.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exact query and its SQL you are trying to modify?

Comment: I would like to execute a query like this: SELECT ID, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' group by guid order by post_date

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution; use pre_get_posts:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_attachments' );

function modify_attachments( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 'admin-ajax.php' ) !== false ) {      
        add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'group_attachments' );
    }
 return $query;
}

function group_attachments( $groupby ) {  
    $groupby .= " guid";
    return $groupby;        
}
```